# Magento 2: How to add BARDCODE

Tags: magento2

I have created attribute "Bardcode EAN".

Stores --> Attributes --> Product --> BARDCODE (kod ean):
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now should display field during add new product but no display this field.

I see new field in columns:
[image]

But when adds a new product, does not have this field to fill it.

Comment: @Solved I have assign to new created attirbute to group default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set this product attribute to your attribute set, by default it would be "default" attribute set.

To set this go in `Stores->Attributes->Attribute Sets` and drag your attribute from "Unassigned attributes" into desired location in groups and save the attribute set.